# Win10: pip install gives error: Unable to find vcvarsall.bat when I want to install cx_Freeze

Tags: python, python-3.x, batch-file, pip, cx-freeze

On Windows 10 I tried to install cx_Freeze with Python 3.5.0 |Anaconda 2.4.0 (64-bit) using:

```
pip install cx_Freeze
```

However, I got this error:

```
 error: Unable to find vcvarsall.bat
```

This is the error and some lines above and below the error:

```
 creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\cx_Freeze\samples\zope
 copying cx_Freeze\samples\zope\qotd.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\cx_Freeze\samples\zope
 copying cx_Freeze\samples\zope\setup.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\cx_Freeze\samples\zope
 running build_ext
 building 'cx_Freeze.util' extension
 error: Unable to find vcvarsall.bat

 ----------------------------------------
 Failed building wheel for cx-Freeze
 Running setup.py clean for cx-Freeze
Failed to build cx-Freeze
Installing collected packages: cx-Freeze
 Running setup.py install for cx-Freeze ... error
 Complete output from command c:\users\rachin_doug\anaconda3\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\RACHIN~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-build-sllgirs1\\cx-Freeze\\setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\RACHIN~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-7d4trlig-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
```

and

```
creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\cx_Freeze\samples\zope
copying cx_Freeze\samples\zope\qotd.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\cx_Freeze\samples\zope
copying cx_Freeze\samples\zope\setup.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\cx_Freeze\samples\zope
running build_ext
building 'cx_Freeze.util' extension
error: Unable to find vcvarsall.bat

----------------------------------------
Command "c:\users\rachin_doug\anaconda3\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\RACHIN~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-build-sllgirs1\\cx-Freeze\\setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\RACHIN~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-7d4trlig-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\RACHIN~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-sllgirs1\cx-Freeze\
```

I have already installed Microsoft Visual Studio 2013 before I had tried to install cx_Freeze.

I have tried the following ideas I found in the Internet:

I modified the `msvc9compiler.py` on line 241 from `toolskey = "VS%0.f0COMNTOOLS" % version` to `toolskey = "VS120COMNTOOLS"`;

I creat the term `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\VisualStudio\9.0\Setup\VC` and the new string value(name=productdir, data=the path of 'vcvarsall.bat') under the term.

After trying those ideas I still got the same error.

Comment: uninstall  `cx_Freeze with Python 3.5.0 |Anaconda 2.4.0 (64-bit)` do a disk cleanup, restart and re-install it again and don't  modify compilers unless you 100% sure of what you are doing

Answer (score 0):

The combination of Python 3.5 and Microsoft Visual Studio 2013 is probably not supported. The compiler requirements are stated in [WindowsCompilers page](https://wiki.python.org/moin/WindowsCompilers#Which_Microsoft_Visual_C.2B-.2B-_compiler_to_use_with_a_specific_Python_version_.3F): in the case of python 3.5 Visual C++ version 14.0 (Visual Studio 2015) is needed.